# what is the difference between positive and negative feedback in an opamp? which is used when?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-electronics, signal-processing

how is it said that opamp with negative feedback operates in linear region?and positive feedback is unstable? then how do we use positive feedback in schmitt trigger?

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research.

Comment: i never look up what is in the help center.  or what makes for "sufficient" preliminary research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want an amplifier or filter or anything linear, better use negative feedback.

if you want a [Schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) or need to implement [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) in some device (like a [multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator) which is a form of [oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator)), then you want to hook it up with positive feedback.